# Get the list of items from the database that is separated with comma for an each record in MVC?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

To Store into database through Listbox (Multiselect) refer the below link

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Get-ListBox-Selected-Text-and-Selected-Value-in-Controller.aspx

Here this link actually alert the messagebox of the listed items in the listbox.

As the referred link above... i stored the data of fruits separated through comma   of multiple items like
var items = string.Join(",", fruits.FruitsId.ToArray());

Output below is

ID       |    Fruits     |    Mobileno
1       |    1,5,4    |     9876543210
2       | 2,3,8       |  9876542103

But now i actually need to fetch the data from  the database of particular record based on mobileno entered in the textbox with the records of fruitslist in the table through ado.net...

This is how i inserted the data into fruits table using ado.net

```
   public void Addfruits(Fruits bfitems)
   {
            try   
            {
             connection(); 
            var items = string.Join(",", bfitems.FruitsId.ToArray());
            string insertText = "insert into FruitItems(Items,Mobileno) 
                VALUES (@Items,@Mobileno)";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertText, con);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", items);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobileno", bfitems.Mobileno);
            if (insertText != null)
            {
                con.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

To fetch the records ....

```
     private static List<SelectListItem> GetFruits(Fruits bf)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        string constr = 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["orders"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = " SELECT * FROM FruitItems where 
            Mobileno=@Mobileno";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobileno", bf.Mobileno);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

        }

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried SQL WHERE clause ?

Comment: Yup where mobileno='9876543210' but i am not getting the list of items... of  particular record

Comment: @Shyju Can you post what you already tried to fetch the record?

Comment: I am not sure the code which is written to fetch is rite or wrong ..Please suggest me to find the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

The `ExecuteNonQuery` executes your query and returns the number records affected by the query (how many rows are inserted/updated). If you want to get data from your table, you should use `ExecuteReader` method which returns a `SqlDataReader`

```
private static List<SelectListItem> GetFruits(Fruits bf)
{
    var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    string constr = "Your connection string here";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        var query = " SELECT ID, Fruits FROM FruitItems where Mobileno=@Mobileno";
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobileno", bf.Mobileno);
            con.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var item = new SelectListItem();
                        item.Value = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id")).ToString();
                        item.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Fruits"));
                        items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

The value you store in the `Fruits` property is comma separated Id values like `1,5,4`. So that is what your SelectListItem's `Text` property is going to have. You probably want to consider normalizing your table to store 1 FruitId value in in a single column(and record).

I excluded the null checks before reading from the SqlDataReader with the assumption that your ID column is NOT NULL type. If it is nullable type, You can use the `IsDBNull` method as needed

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Id")))
{
    item.Value = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id")).ToString();
}
```

Comment: how do you get the records in the table format in the view ?

Comment: use HTML table to render a table. In that case, why would you use `SelectListItem` from your code ? create a class to represent your data and return that.

Comment: Why do m getting this error......    The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Orders.Models.Fruits'.

Comment: because your view is strongly typed to a list of Fruit objects and it expects that. But your action method is trying to pass a list of SelectListItem objects. Pass the correct data

Answer (score 0):

```
@model Orders.Models.Fruits
@using (Html.BeginForm())  
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">       
    <h2>Fruits</h2>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobileno, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtmobno", @Placeholder = "Mobile" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobileno, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>ItemsID</th>
                <th>Items</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var items in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@items.ItemsId</td>
                    <td>@items.Items</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Print" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

}